# CruiseControl.net reports SVN locked exception

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net, locked

I am trying to setup a CruiseControl.net (version 1.4.4) server on a machine with Windows XP SP3. The source is contained in an SVN repository on a different server. The svn client I am using was installed through the Cygwin tools.

I am able to get CruiseControl.net successfully installed and configured up to getting the Subversion part working. Everytime modifications are detected or a build is forced, CruiseControl.net throws an expception complaining that the working copy is locked and to run svn cleanup. I have tried playing around with the source control block elements and their settings. I have tried including the  element and manually running svn cleanup on the local working copy - but no luck. Is there something else I need to configure in order to get Subversion working with CruiseControl.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use the cygwin svn client. There's no reason to use that since there's a perfectly fine [svn client for Windows](http://subversion.tigris.org/getting.html#windows). And the cygwin client has several problems (wc format, line endings, ...).

Comment: Thanks, I just tried the CollabNet client before checking back here, and it resolved my issue.